# What to do when serial downvoting is not fully reversed?

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I've been a 'victim' of a serial downvoter recently, so as other questions' answers say, I waited 24h. to let the point correction trigger. In sum, I was taken 12 points.

> [image: rev1]

So when it actually triggered, it were just 8 points that I was given back.

> [image: rev2]

I know this is automatic and is based on an heuristic, so it's not perfect, but my question is: What should be done when the reversal won't return all the points? Should users notify it on meta, or these situations are just ok and shouldn't be reported?

Comment: The last two downvotes, those at 21:52, were not reverted. Most likely because they were done by a different user.

Comment: I think that the different minute would be the reason why it was not reversed, but I'm sure it's from the same user, I've not been active at all since a few weeks, I don't get any up/downvotes and these answers are relatively old.

Comment: No, the serial voting script is not limited to votes in a single minute window. If they had been by the same account they'd be reverted too.

Comment: It *could* be that the votes were cast by someone using a sock-puppet account to try and avoid the serial voting script. We have no solid evidence here, of course.

Comment: This is of course trivially fixed.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

You should either flag one of your posts and explain what happened or ask a moderator in the [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chat room.

Source: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857)

Comment: I should point out that there's often little we can do about a case like this, since we can't see who left individual votes, nor can we invalidate them. We'll have to pull in one of the community team members if we feel it's worth acting on. You might be better off writing the community team directly via email and explaining the situation. Even then, just a couple of votes might not be enough for them to justify the reversal effort.

Comment: Yes, surely this is not the case where it's worth bothering the community team members, it's just a few points, I was just curious about how to procceed in such situations. Thanks!

Comment: Emphasis on _one_ of the posts--after a slow drip downvoting campaign, I flagged about 10 answers that had been downvoted, but my flags were declined with the reason "Declined - Only need one flag for this" and "Declined - duplicate flag".

Answer (score 3):

Some smart enough rep-whores, who are too much offended with downvotes for their pointless answers, simply register additional accounts. Not to foolishly vote for themselves but to make their revenge.

> What should be done when the reversal won't return all the points?

Shake off that delusion. These are just virtual numbers. That's nothing, void. Do not whine for losing just a few of them. Get a life. Move on.

Answer (score 2):

Accept that any qualitative scoring system is inherently flawed and be glad that there is serial downvoting detection at all.

Comment: I know that and I really appreciate that system, I just ask if it's ok to claim them back or not :-)

Comment: I am not a moderator nor do I wish to be one. If I were, it would probably strike me as picayune to argue for a few reputation points.